# LINQ sum returns wrong result

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a table with rows containing the following numbers:

```
4191808.51
3035280.22
3437796.06
4013772.33
1740652.56
0
```

The sum of that table is `16419309.68`.

When I do a Linq SUM query on that table, it returns a whole different number: `19876858.14`

The code I use to do the sum is as follows:

```
IEnumerable<MyData> data = _myRepository.GetMatching(myValue);
decimal sumSales = data.Sum(x => x.Sales);
```

What could be causing this? I suspect some max decimal value but couldn't find info on that

Comment: please write your queries here.

Comment: profile/view the sql generated

Comment: If one of the returning numbers would be decimal.MaxValue - you will not be able to do SUM because it will be more that decimal variable sumSales  can have

Answer (score 0):

can you please examine your

```
IEnumerable<MyData> data = _myRepository.GetMatching(myValue);
```

in the debugger after the execution. I'm suspecting that you are selecting some different set of data - not what you have shown in the sample. I attempted to recreated you situation LinqPad, but constantly getting the correct answer.

```
decimal[] data = {
    4191808.51m
    ,3035280.22m
    ,3437796.06m
    ,4013772.33m
    ,1740652.56m
    ,0m
};

decimal sumSales = data.Sum();
sumSales.Dump();
```

and getting: **16419309.68**